# How to test ask pattern with fallback

Tags: scala, akka

I have an actor, that asks other actor and future can fallbacks to other:

```
class Subject(db: ActorRef) extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(1 seconds)
  implicit val ec = context.system.dispatcher

  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    db ? "auth" fallbackTo Future {
      "auth:timeout_error"
    } pipeTo self
  }

  def receive: Receive = {
    case msg: String => log.info(msg)
  }

}
```

I need to test fallback behavior, but don't know how to do it:

```
class ActorSpec extends TestKit(ActorSystem("MySpec"))
  with ImplicitSender with WordSpecLike with BeforeAndAfterAll with BeforeAndAfterEach with Matchers {

  val db = TestProbe()

  db.ref ! PoisonPill
  //db not exist anymore
  val subject = system.actorOf(Props(new Subject(db.ref)))

  //Something like: subject should receive "auth:timeout_error"

}
```

How to carry out this task properly?

Comment: Maybe what you want to have is some sort of a state machine? Ie. the subject is first in state `initializing` and as soon as it receives the response from the `db` actor, it is either in `failed` or `running`? See `context.become`.

Comment: @rethab Yes, state machine suits for that. But how I can test, that actor becomes `failed`? My question more general about test practice. Typical actor test looks like: "send message to subject, verify it state, verify correct response". But in my scenario, I need verify, that subject receives(!) correct message.

Comment: What I usually do: Either I add explicit query messages where I could ask the subject whether it is in state `running` or I would send a message to the the subject which I know it only handles if it is in state `running`. If I get a response, it is in state running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to perform the testing would be to refactor your `Subject` class to add a level of abstraction to the `db` parameter.  There is nothing in `Subject` that inherently depends on the fact that db is an `ActorRef`; `Subject` simply needs something to send a query `String` to and receive a `Future[String]` response.  Therefore you can make the constructor more generic by taking in a function:

```
object Subject {
  type Query = String
  type DBResult = Future[String]
  type DB : (Query) => DBResult

  val defaultAuth : DBResult = Future.successful("auth:timeout_error")

  val authQuery : Query = "auth"

  def queryWithDefault(db : DB, default : DBResult = defaultAuth) : DB = 
    (query : Query) => db(query) fallbackTo default     
}//end object Subject

class Subject(db : Subject.DB) extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  override def preStart() : Unit = {
    db(Subject.authQuery) pipeTo self
  }

  override def receive : Receive = {
    case msg : String => log info msg
  }
}//end class Subject
```

You can now test the `queryWithDefault` function without having to use akka at all:

```
import org.scalatest.{Matchers, WordSpecLike}
import org.scalatest.concurrent.ScalaFutures

class SubjectSpec 
  extends Matchers 
  with WorkSpecLike 
  with ScalaFutures {

  val alwaysFail : DB = 
    (query : Query) => Future.failed(new Exception("always fails"))

  import Subject.{defaultAuth, queryWithDefault, authQuery}

  "queryWithDefault" should {
    "always return default when db fails" in {
      val db = queryWithDefault(alwaysFail, defaultAuth)

      whenReady(
        for {
          authQueryRes <- db(authQuery)
          fooQueryRes  <- db("foo")
          defaultRes   <- defaultAuth
        }) {
          authQueryRes shouldEqual defaultRes
          fooQueryRes shouldEqual defaultRes 
        }
    }//end "always return..."
  }//end "queryWithDefault" should
}//end class SubjectSpec
```

You can then use the refactored, and unit tested, `Subject.queryWithDefault` function in production:

```
val actorDB : DB = (query : Query) => (db.ref ? query).mapTo[String]

val subject = system.actorOf(Props(queryWithDefault(actorDB, defaultAuth)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override receive method and send message to your TestProbe()

```
val probe = TestProbe()

db.ref ! PoisonPill

val actor = system.actorOf(Props(new Subject(db.ref) {
    override def receive: Received = {
      case message => probe.ref ! message
    }
}))

probe.expectMsg("auth:timeout_error")
```